# Incorrect JavaScript Result for Project Euler Problem

Tags: javascript, typescript

> Consider all integer combinations of a<sup>b</sup> for 2 ≤ a ≤ 5 and 2 ≤ b ≤ 5:
>
> 2<sup>2</sup>=4, 2<sup>3</sup>=8, 2<sup>4</sup>=16, 2<sup>5</sup>=32
> 3<sup>2</sup>=9, 3<sup>3</sup>=27, 3<sup>4</sup>=81, 3<sup>5</sup>=243
> 4<sup>2</sup>=16, 4<sup>3</sup>=64, 4<sup>4</sup>=256, 4<sup>5</sup>=1024
> 5<sup>2</sup>=25, 5<sup>3</sup>=125, 5<sup>4</sup>=625, 5<sup>5</sup>=3125
>
> If they are then placed in numerical order, with any repeats removed, we get the following sequence of 15 distinct terms:
>
> ```
> 4, 8, 9, 16, 25, 27, 32, 64, 81, 125, 243, 256, 625, 1024, 3125
> ```
>
> How many distinct terms are in the sequence generated by a<sup>b</sup> for 2 ≤ a ≤ 100 and 2 ≤ b ≤ 100?
>
> https://projecteuler.net/problem=29

```js
var numberarray =[];
var numberr;

for(var a = 1; a++ <101;){
    for (var b =1; b++<101;){
        numberr = a ** b
        isexist = numberarray.includes(numberr)
        if(isexist == false){
            numberarray.push(numberr)
        }
    }
}

console.log(numberarray.length);
```

here is my problem, answer is 9183, but my solution saying answer is 9382. where is the problem.

Comment: actually, your code outputs 9419

Comment: @atılgan [I see 9419](https://i.imgur.com/IjYpCMP.png)

Comment: The issue is in your for statements, it's missing a semi-colon.

Comment: I suspect you are going through software numeric overflow, a very lengthy exponential number

Comment: @Evert i have not a writing error, javascript ignores semi-colon errors, i just have a logic error. Answer must be 9183.

Comment: @atılgan `b++<101` is not the same as `b++; b<101` and also not the same as `++b<101`. It is relevant here

Comment: @Evert It's not strictly necessary to split it that way; what OP has "works" as is (for certain definitions of "works").

Comment: @deceze read the problem statement on project Euler. Clearly not what OP intended in this case.

Comment: @Evert [but it doesn't produce 9183 - it produces 9308](https://jsbin.com/moqixumufu/edit?js,console)

Comment: Ah, there's a second problem. The numbers will be outside of the 'safe integer' range and will convert to float. That might have something to do with this too. I think this problem might be one of the early excercizes in how to deal with numbers that don't fit in an integer.

Comment: @Evert they won't convert to a float. 1. all numbers in JS are floats anyway 2. Even then an *integer* bigger than MAX_SAFE_INTEGER will still remain an integer - its value is just not precise and might (and very likely *does*) gets represented as another integer.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I used a wrong definition. But yes, its beyond MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, and I can imagine that 2 calculations that *should* yield the same integer, might not in floating point math.

Comment: I just got 9382, adjusting for the issue with numbers > MAX_SAFE_INTEGER. I don't think it's in the spririt of project euler to hand the answer, but the problem certainly is there.

Comment: try `BigInt` in javascript you will get full number without exponent

Answer (score -1, accepted):

increment right hand is different then left hand

Your loop includes `101` that is the issue

Try this code

```js
var numberarray = [];
var numberr;

for (var a = 1; ++a < 101;) {
  for (var b = 1; ++b < 101;) {
    var numberr = a ** b;
    isexist = numberarray.includes(numberr)
    if (isexist == false) {
      console.log(numberr)
      numberarray.push(numberr)
    }
  }
}

console.log(numberarray.length);
```

Output:

```
9183
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211560/discussion-on-answer-by-dickens-a-s-incorrect-javascript-result-for-project-eule).

Comment: Note: this produces different results `9220` in Firefox and `9183` in Chrome. The problems are numbers larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. I did some investigation on the difference. The first discrepancy is the product `3 ** 35`. In Firefox that is `50031545098999704` while in Chrome it's `50031545098999710`. Yet both are wrong, as the result is [50031545098999707](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3+%5E+35). So, both calculations are off by 3 here. So, it's possible that this produces the correct answer by accident. I cannot guarantee it's a reliable way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 issues in your source.

1. Your loop is pretty strange. This line:

```
for(var a = 1; a++ <101;){
```

Will cause a loop with the numbers 2, 3, until 101. So it starts at 2 and ends at 101.

This can be fixed as such:

```
for(var a = 1; ++a <101;){
```

(thanks Dickens A S), but a more reasonable way to write this is:

```
for(var a = 2; a<101; a++){
```

Second problem:

Javascript has (for its normal `number` type) a cap to what numbers can be safely represented. This is also called `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, or `9007199254740991`.

Numbers above this lose precision. You no longer get exact outcomes.

This means that in if you there are 2 calculations that normally yield the same result, for example:

```
a ** b === c ** d
```

This is *not* always true in Javascript, due to the fact that math with large number might get non-exact results. So this is really a variation of 'dont do exact comparisons with floating point math'.

It's against the spirit of project euler to hand you the answer, so I won't write it down. If you really want to, you can probably find it anyway. However, I validated this by making 2 adjustments and got exactly 9183.

Another edit: It turns out that for some people with Chrome you do get correct answers, even without fixing the large number problem. Important to note that this is unreliable though. Not understanding this problem here will probably give you headaches in later Euler problems. (Thank you VLAZ)

Comment: for his equation reference, The Euler equation starts will power `2`, power `1` is skipped, may be the loop itself should start a=2

Comment: @Evert not THAT surprising but it's definitely non-idiomatic, thus hard to read. `a` is initialised as `1` then *during the check* is incremented by 1. The check runs once before the first iteration (to see whether the iteration is needed), so once *inside* the first iteration `a = 2`.

Comment: @VLAZ I got confused and tripped up over my own code during testing this. This loop syntax just messed with my brain i guess! I'm now pretty confident my answer is complete though.

Comment: `for(var a = 1; a++; a<101){` wait, I don't think this *works*. It should produce an infinite loop, since `a++` is where the condition should be and is thus always going to be truthy, thus the loop will never terminate.

Comment: Yep, just killed my Chrome tab trying this to make sure I didn't miss anything. Yeah, works now when the two are swapped.